# cygwin sshd fatal seteuid Invalid argument

Tags: cygwin, sshd

recently I'm unable to connect to cygwin sshd server

```
$ ssh 127.0.0.1 -vvvv
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/config
debug1: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/config line 13: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 127.0.0.1 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:22 as 'Gowtham'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 127.0.0.1
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:VJlYVlARWd+ePWzrElRNWS6tQTifgP+2T/3H10VsJBI
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 127.0.0.1
debug1: Host '127.0.0.1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:esZqwl/G7s7v6cHEcgQbCQuaiFeegR1CeXetZUKv/lY
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /cygdrive/c/Users/Gowtham/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:esZqwl/G7s7v6cHEcgQbCQuaiFeegR1CeXetZUKv/lY
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 22
```

**Event Xml from cygsshd server:**

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="sshd" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">0</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-08-06T07:15:22.035892700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>11803</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Blizlac</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>sshd: PID 1920: fatal: seteuid 197609: Invalid argument</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I think the error started to show up after system update.

Windows 10.0, Build 18363

Comment: I know this is old but I'll add this: for me it was showing up as `seteuid 1234/5678: Invalid argument`.  The problem was the 2nd part (5678) was a domain group (you can check these with the `id` command), which means I needed to be locally signed in to the VPN so it could see the domain controller in order to set the UID.  That took me a minute to figure out.

Comment: i moved from cygwin to msys2

Answer (score 1):

I've run into exactly the same case and error information.
As a result of various checks, in my environment, it seems that the user ID of the Windows server and the user ID of Cygwin were not synchronized.

Execute the following command in Cygwin and check if the result matches the information in the target user section of `/etc/passwd` in the Cygwin environment.

```
mkpasswd -l -u [user name]
```

In my environment, since the user ID did not match, the problem was solved by correcting the `/etc/passwd` value.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the initial user with which i've installed cygwin. Deleting all cygwin files and registry entries and reinstalling cygwin fixed the issue. I wish I knew exactly on what files i have to change user permissions. I hope someone answers it.